# Understanding 'next' in ruby - comparing solutions

Tags: ruby, iteration

I'm doing an online course:

> Write a method that takes a string and returns `true` if the letter `"z"` appears within three letters **after** an `"a"`. You may assume that the string contains only lowercase letters.

This is the solution given:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if string[i] != "a"
      i += 1
      next
    end
    j = i + 1
    while (j < string.length) && (j <= i + 3)
      if string[j] == "z"
        return true
      end
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return false
end
```

This solution seems unnecessarily complex to me. Specifically, I don't understand why `next` is needed. I was wondering if someone could help me understand this function.

My solution appears to work as well with the tests I tried, but I'm wondering if the other solution is better and if my solution would have problems that I just haven't come across yet.

```
def nearby_az(string)
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    while string[i] != "a"
      i += 1
    end
    if string[i + 1] == "z" || string[i + 2] == "z" || string[i + 3] == "z"
      return true
    else
      i += 1
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: As you gain experience with Ruby you will discover that this question can be answered most easily by using a regular expression ("regex"). If `str` is your string, you can simply write `str =~ /a.{,2}z/`. This reads, "match an 'a' followed by any letter (`.`) between zero and two times (`{,2}` or `{0,2}`), followed by a 'z'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original answer, if you remove `next`, the `i` index will be assumed to be representing an `"a"` position even if it is not, and will return a wrong result.

When you pass a string like `"b"` to your code, it will go into an endless loop because the outer condition `while i < string.length` has no control over:

```
while string[i] != "a"
  i += 1
end
```

Notice that, once `i` is beyond the last position of a string, the condition `string[i]` becomes `nil`, and `string[i] != "a"` will be satisfied from there on.

Comment: 0 >= 0, so the outer loop will not allow an empty string.

Comment: @TimTom Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will not work if the string will look like this "bbbbb..." or like this "abb" - that is -
1) your code will crash if string.length < 4 (no string[i+3])
2) your code will crash if no "a"s are in the string.
And here the "next" came in handy:
The purpose of the "next" is to skip the rest of the loop and jump right back to the start of it. So the original solution will first go over chars until it finds on "a" (skipping the other part of the loop is not) and when and only when it finds "a" - it goes to find the "z".

Comment: It will not crash.

Answer (score 1):

So, as sawa stated, your loop doesn't accept strings without an a in them. It also doesn't understand strings with multiple a's. For example aaaaaaaz will return false because it finds the first a, checks the next 3 doesn't find a z and bails out.

You can solve your problem by removing the return false from the end and adding the same length condition as the outer loop to the inner loop.

His use of next is equivalent to the above.  It is a way of threading the two things together. It is needlessly complex though, I agree.

A far simpler way (assuming you don't want to use regexps) is to just track the last occurance of an 'a'.

```
def nearby_az(string)
  last_a = -4
  string.chars.each_with_index do |c, i|
    last_a = i if c == 'a'
    return true if c == 'z' and i - last_a <= 3
  end
  return false
end
```